# iPhone safari browser autofill Contact is filling all First name or Last name fields

Tags: html, css, angular

For my webpage there are several form fields like First Name, Last Name Address etc in ng-repeat.I am facing one issue only in iphone safari browser while selecting data for first name from autofill contact, automatically other first name fields are getting filled up. Same thing is applicable for all other similar kind of fields like Last Name.

I have used unique ID and name values for all form fields. no work.
This strange behavior is happening only if I provide, 'First', 'First Name', 'F name', 'fname' in label/ID/name. Label name present in label, span div tag before field.

First Name

Comment: Can you give a [mcve] to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: When you use Safari autocomplete, it will fill all fields it thinks it can fill with propper information. But could you explain why this is a problem in your application?

Comment: Hi Tim, I have three First name form fields for 3 different passengers. When I am filling the data for first passenger first name field from autofill contact, other two passengers first name are getting filled with same data automatically.  You can check Delta.com website in your iphone safari browser.